# How can I find my phone without an app

Tags: lost-phone

I just lost my phone today and I dont have any Find Me app but I am logged in with all of my information. Like my email, facebook, and such things. How can I possibly find it?? I also know that my GPS is set on On.

Answer (score 0):

You could log into to your Google account and check your location history...assuming you've turned on Latitude:  https://latitude.google.com/latitude/b/0/